# How can I disallow code merge if checks and Teamcity build failed?

Tags: github, teamcity, github-codereviews

I am trying to do code reviews with GitHub and Teamcity. I want to place a Git Merge protection gatecheck, since last time, people placed compilation errors in our team Develop Git Branch. We know how to conduct Teamcity builds linking to Git.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/08/building-github-pull-requests-with-teamcity/

However, come time during actual Git Merge, I want to deny the merge if the Teamcity build failed.

How can I do that in Github?

Comment: You can't do it in raw Git, but GitHub do provide the notion of a *protected branch*. This protection is rather all-or-nothing (though I think you can make one protect against normal users but not against administrators). Whether that's sufficient for your purposes, I don't know.

Comment: hi @torek feel free to write as answer, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: I'm not a GitHub expert; you should look up questions of the form "how to make GitHub protected branches", for which I'm sure there are many answers (including on GitHub's own documentation).